# Audiomath TypeError - MakeRise, MakeFade, MakeHannWindow

Tags: python, numpy, audio, fade, audiomath

I'm using audiomath under Python 3.7 on Windows 10.

I have been using audiomath to standardize my audio files for EEG analyses, it has been very useful for all parameters except this one, I keep stuck when trying to make it create fade-ins, fade-outs or HannWindows.

I've run the same code on other machines with other versions of Python and Numpy and I still get the same error.

```
from audiomath import Sound, MakeRise
import numpy

sound01 = Sound('mySample.wav')
soundFadedIn = sound01.MakeHannWindow(5)
soundFadedIn.Play()
```

[Log Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIYRn.png)

Comment: That looks like a bug in audiomath that will occur with recent versions of numpy.  In older numpy, one can use, e.g., `np.linspace(0, 1, 4.0)` (note that the last argument is floating point).  In newer versions of numpy, that will raise an exception like the one you are getting; the third argument must be an integer type.

Comment: You could create a new issue about this in the audiomath issue tracker at https://bitbucket.org/snapproject/audiomath-gitrepo/issues?status=new&status=open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @WarrenWeckesser, this was a bug in `audiomath`, which has been fixed in `audiomath` version 1.16.0+

Note that `MakeHannWindow` only returns the Hann weighting itself (with duration and sampling-frequency matched to `sound01`). It does not return the sound *multiplied by* the weighting as you seem to have assumed. What you seem to be trying to do may be better accomplished using the `.Fade()` method (which was also affected by the same bug).

With a little modification, the way you did it is one way to do it (it always gives you a symmetric fade-in **and** -out, optionally specifying the duration of the plateau in the middle, in seconds):

```
from audiomath import Sound

sound01 = Sound('mySample.wav')
soundFadedInAndOut = sound01 * sound01.MakeHannWindow(5)  # note the multiplication
```

Or here's another, where you specify the duration of the rising and falling sections explicitly and separately, instead (it doesn't have to be symmetric, and either of the two durations can be 0):

```
from audiomath import Sound

sound01 = Sound('mySample.wav')
soundFadedInAndOut = sound01.Copy().Fade(risetime=0.5, falltime=0.5, hann=True)
```

Finally, if for some reason you're unable or unwilling to upgrade `audiomath` to 1.16, a workaround for the bug you're reporting might be to use the `Shoulder()` function from `audiomath.Signal` to generate your windowing function:

```
import audiomath as am, numpy as np

x = am.Sound('mySample.wav')
endFadeIn, startFadeOut = 0.5, x.duration-0.5
t = np.linspace(0, x.duration, x.nSamples) # in seconds
window = am.Signal.Shoulder(t, [0, endFadeIn, startFadeOut, x.duration])  # it's a numpy array, not a Sound
faded = x * window   # but you can still multiply a Sound by it
faded.Play()
```